# Passing a datatable from C# Asp.Net website to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm having a dataset containing multiple datatables in my aspx file

I need a datatable to be passed into an SQL Server stored procdure so that I can modify the table and insert into a database table in SQL Server

The Datasets contain huge data present in it

Can you Help me out!

Comment: You can pass a `DataTable` to a stored procedure using the [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 and newer. The recommendation is to use TVP for up to about 1'000 rows - use `SqlBulkCopy` for larger sets of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass data sets to a stored procedure. Even though table variables are a language element of t-sql it isn't possible to use them for passing data into a procedure. You can encode the data table as a CSV/XML string, but encoding/decoding would have a huge impact on performance. You may want to implement the logic in your data layer on the C# side and just input the results into the database.

Comment: Thank you sir but
can you help me in sending a datatable from c# into a xml string
and retrieving it in sql server?

Comment: *The Datasets contain huge data present in it* --> you really shouldn't do this. But if you insist, have a look at these articles on transforming a dataset to xml (http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx) and reading xml in the sql server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (better have experience in xpath)

Comment: You **CAN** however pass a `DataTable` using the [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) in SQL Server 2008 and newer...

Comment: @marc_s very interesting approach, maybe this solves the OPs question

Comment: If i shouldn't do this what i have to do in order to insert data from the datatable into multiple sql server tables

Comment: what about "outsourcing" this part of logic to your C# layer?

Comment: Thank you marc_s
The use of table valued parameters really helped me solving my problem
however i have to create a datatype for each and every table i insert into my database